# How to install support for GStreamer element ffdeinterlace?

Tags: 14.04, gstreamer, subtitle, arista-transcoder

On Ubuntu 14.04 I am trying to use Arista Transducer to burn subtitle to an mp3 file. But I keep getting this error:

```
Python (v2.7) requires to install plugins to support the following multimedia feature: GStreamer element ffdeinterlace
```

When I check all the available Gstreamer plugins on the repository are installed. So wondering how to fix this issue?

Comment: This is a guess out of the blue, but maybe you could need the package `python-gst-1.0`?

Comment: I installed `python-gst-1.0`. Now the error is gone but nothing happens when I click `Create`.

Comment: Sorry, no idea. I neither know the program you use, nor do I know GStreamer well. I just searched for a Python Gstreamer interface package... :-/

Answer (score 1):

For some reason gstreamer plugins changed names and since Arista developers have not changed their dependencies it won't work fine. I've fixed this before by adding the gstreamer plugins on their ppa or by including older repositories (I recommend 12.04)

Comment: Would you please elaborate how to do that?

Comment: include the repositories for ubuntu 12.04 in your /etc/apt/sources.list and after apt-get update do a apt-get install gstreamer-(the package you need). this solved the problem for me once.